# Can I use if() in formatting a lattice key?

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to make a graph in lattice, and have the key appear based on a logical variable. That is, it will only appear if the logical variable is true (this will be on a R-shiny website and the user will indicate if they want a key). The catch is that I would like the key to appear to the right of the graph - not in the plotting region.

I can use the `key=` and get the key on the right using the `space="right"` option, but there is no obvious way to turn on and off the key

Or I can use `draw.key()` function and turn the key on and off using the `draw=` option, but then the key is in the plotting area and not to the right. So I thought I would use a `if()` statement to trigger the `key` option - but that does not work. No key is drawn and the logical statement is ignored. How can I get this to work?

Reproducible example:

```
library(lattice)

A<-rnorm(1:100)
B<-rnorm(1:100)
K<-TRUE

xyplot(A~B,
   if(K==TRUE) {
      key=list(lines=list(color="blue")), space="right") 
    },

    panel=function(x,y,...){
       panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
    }
)
```

**Edit to add**: In other parts of the code, if statements are used to trigger which elements appear in the key, which makes this even more mysterious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value of the if-statement to `key` (in the correct scope):

```
xyplot(A~B, key=
   if(K) {
      key=list(lines=list(color="blue"))
    },

    panel=function(x,y,...){
       panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
    }
)
```

(You could drop the inner `key=`)

Comment: Thanks - I did not think about the scoping issue at all! I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: And thanks for the good compact example. It makes testing so much quicker.